# insert two values from an mysql table into another table using a python program

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm having a small problem with a Python program (below) that I'm writing.

I want to insert two values from a MySQL table into another table from a Python program.

The two fields are priority and product and I have selected them from the shop table and I want to insert them into the products table.

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot. Marc.

```
import MySQLdb

def checkOut():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user = 'root', passwd = '$$', db = 'fillmyfridge')
    cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    user_input = raw_input('please enter the product barcode that you are taking out of the fridge: \n')
    cursor.execute('update shops set instock=0, howmanytoorder = howmanytoorder + 1  where barcode = %s', (user_input))
    db.commit()
    cursor.execute('select product, priority from shop where barcode = %s', (user_input))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute('insert into products(product, barcode, priority) values (%s, %s)', (rows["product"], user_input, rows["priority"]))
    db.commit()
    print 'the following product has been removed from the fridge and needs to be ordered'
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please write an actual question as a sentence with capital letters and a question mark.  Could you rewrite your posting to include an actual question?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the same thing again:

```
import MySQLdb

def checkOut():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user = 'root', passwd = '$$', db = 'fillmyfridge')
    cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    user_input = raw_input('please enter the product barcode that you are taking out of the fridge: \n')
    cursor.execute('update shops set instock=0, howmanytoorder = howmanytoorder + 1  where barcode = %s', (user_input))
    db.commit()
    cursor.execute('select product, priority from shop where barcode = %s', (user_input))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

1. Do you need fetchall()?? Barcode's are unique I guess and one barcode is to one product I guess. So, fetchone() is enough....isn't it??
2. In any case if you do a fetchall() its a result set not a single result.
   So `rows["product"]` is not valid.
   It has to be

   ```
   for row in rows:
       cursor.execute('insert into products(product, barcode, priority) values (%s, %s, %s)', (row["product"], user_input, row["priority"]))
   db.commit()
   print 'the following product has been removed from the fridge and needs to be ordered'
   ```

or better

```
import MySQLdb

def checkOut():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user = 'root', passwd = '$$', db = 'fillmyfridge')
    cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    user_input = raw_input('please enter the product barcode that you are taking out of the fridge: \n')
    cursor.execute('update shops set instock=0, howmanytoorder = howmanytoorder + 1  where barcode = %s', (user_input))
    cursor.execute('insert into products(product, barcode, priority) select product, barcode, priority from shop where barcode = %s', (user_input))
    db.commit()
```

**Edit:** Also, you use `db.commit()` almost like `print` - anywhere, you need to read and understand the [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) principle for databases

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what the problem is, but in the code you show this:

```
cursor.execute('insert into products(product, barcode, priority) values (%s, %s)', (rows["product"], user_input, rows["priority"]))
```

where your values clause only has two %s's in it, where it should have three:

```
cursor.execute('insert into products(product, barcode, priority) values (%s, %s, %s)', (rows["product"], user_input, rows["priority"]))
```

Comment: @Ned: is `rows` scriptable? isn't it a resultset after fetchall() it needs indices I believe. m I think in the wrong direction?

Comment: though, no issues over that typo. Even I didn't notice that.